# Passing a Symfony4 @Route paramaeter in to the construct of a controller

Tags: routes, symfony4

I need to pass a URL Route parameter in to a construct to perform a basic security check on all the routes for a particular class but I don't know how to pass the route parameter in to the Controller construct function

Simplified code as follows:

```
/**
 * @Route("/stores/{store_id}", name="admin_stores",
 */
class ManageStores extends AbstractController
{

    var $store;

    /**
     * ManageStores constructor.
     * @param $store_id
     * @param UserInterface $user
     */
    public function __construct($store_id, UserInterface $user)
    {

        // validation here using parsed
        if ( !$user->canManageStore( $store_id ) )
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login_page');

        // else: continues on to relevant routes in controller


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The route parameters are passed in (via the `Request` object) to the controller action, not constructor. The values aren't known when the container is being configured and built.

You'll need to check permission to access on a per-action basis, though you can shortcut this a little with access control and voters (this is somewhat advanced but there is [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) on them, and some video-walk-throughs also available on setting them up).

Comment: Ah. Voters look interesting. I come from a WordPress background and this seems very much like the user roles/capabilities. I've ended up writing a custom function for now which seems to do what Voters are built for. Will look to replace it with that as time goes on. Thanks for the info :)